# What do the number of contexts in valgrind leak summary refer to?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, memcheck

I was profiling a c++ application using valgrind. In the leak summary, the number of errors is different from the number of contexts. What do contexts mean?

```
`ERROR SUMMARY: 44911 errors from 1070 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)`
```

Why are the number of errors different from the number of contexts in this case?

Comment: "I was profiling a c++" - Which means you should not add C tag.

Comment: ok. got it. it seems to be removed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

context referes to the call stacks that lead to an error.
To put it simple: that many places in the code cause errors.

Comment: ok. That is right. Then, any idea what do the number of errors mean?

Comment: If a error location is being executed more than once you will have more than one error . Consider a case with just one error location that is being executed 10 time you would have "10 errors from 1 contexts"

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition for **context error**:

> the (...) context for the error is the chain of function calls that led (or may led) to an error.

Look at this example in the Error Summary: 
[image: This is the Error Summary]

and here are the two error contexts:
[image: Two invalid write of size 1]

So, to answer you question, the number of context refers to the number of functions in where problems are detected.

In the above example, you should *read each context error from the bottom-up*, and you can identify that both context errors are happening in the `strconk` file, in the 100 and 102 lines.

Please, also notice that for each context error, in the Address section, it shows a description of where that error is happening in memory, "0 bytes after a block of size 6". It is a good clue to **identify exactly** what is causing you troubles.

For detailed information on how Valdrind works, please refer to: https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html

Hope this helps you!

Comment: What does it mean when I have 50 'contexts' but my log only shows, say, 45. So the last line is X errors in context 45 of 50. What happened to the last five? Last line is ERROR SUMMARY: xxx errors from 50 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)